# Sed doesn't take file to work at

Tags: sed, pipe

When i type

```
grep -r string1 folder/ | cut -d ":" -f1 | sed -i -e 's/string1/string2/'
```

it say

```
sed: no imput files
```

but

```
grep -r string1 folder/ | cut -d ":" -f1
```

write in stdOut a list of path who have to following

```
sed -i -e 's/string1/string2/' [here]
```

---

It's not the topic but if you know how to make `sed` just modify the line who BEGIN with `string1` it will help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to optimize this, but the easiest way to fix your immediate problem is:

```
sed -i 's/^string1/string2/g' folder/*
```

This will cause sed to replace instances where `string1` is at the beginning of the line with the string `string2` for all files in `folder/`.

Comment: Okay, it's the same because it will read all the files but only replace instances. But what about adding a "g" ? Global is for replacing multiple times in a same line, i juste want to replace the first word who is `string1`

Comment: another way (he left out xargs):
  
grep -r string1 folder/ | cut -d ":" -f1 | xargs sed -i -e 's/^string1/string2/'

Note: neither of our approaches deals with case sensitivity.

Comment: Remove the `g` then ;)

Comment: I really never understood why people use xarg. I heard that it's a memory-friendly way to operate, but instead of that i dunno

Comment: There are more reasons but for example, if you have a huge amount of files in a directory, the wildcard expansion (`*`) will cause the command to hit the maximum length of a command.  `xargs` will only add arguments up to the maximum command length and run multiple iterations of sed.